# The output when I run code in VSCode gets displayed in the terminal window instead of the output window

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I tried some of the solutions posted earlier in similar questions but none of them seem to work for me. My code is in **Python 3.8** and I am using the **latest version of VSCode**. Thanks.

Comment: Which similar questions? What output did you want? What are you doing? Why are any of us here? It'd be loads more helpful if you told us which question, which code you're using, and what message VSCode is displaying.

Comment: @RoboMop I'm new to stackoverflow. I got the solution, but I'll try to elaborate my questions in future. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running python code in VS Code, it executes the running command in the VS Code internal terminal ( `TERMINAL` ) by default. It is a terminal that allows user interaction, but "`OUTPUT`" is an output terminal, which cannot receive user input.

For how to make the output display in "`OUTPUT`" in VS Code:

Please use the "`Code Runner`" extension in VS Code, which uses "`OUTPUT`" by default:

[image]

In addition, if you want to use relatively clean output, you could also use "`DEBUG CONSOLE`".

Please use in "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)": `"console": "internalConsole",` then click `F5` to debug the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've the code runner extension installed. If yes then,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2jvo.png)
Go to settings ,
1.search Terminal
2. scroll to the last line
3. uncheck code run in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Install "Code Runner" extension.

- VS Code -> Extensions (Ctrl+Shift+X) in the most left panel -> text box "Search Extensions in Marketplace" -> Code Runner -> Install

Setting up Code Runner

- VS Code -> File -> Preferences -> Settings (Ctrl+,) -> text box "Search settings" -> Code Runner -> ensure that checkbox for "Code-runner: Run In Terminal" is unchecked.

Running Python Scripts

- Prepare a Python code you want to run -> Press Ctrl+Alt+N to run the code via Code Runner.
- If the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+N is already taken e.g. by another software, you can change the shortcut

  - File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S) -> search: Code Runner -> Run Code

If you want to clear previous output (from OUTPUT window) -> File -> Preferences -> Settings (Ctrl+,) -> text box "Search settings" -> Code Runner -> ensure that checkbox for "Code-runner: Clear Previous Output" is checked.